# Why explain query is returning NULL on primary key's join

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure if i am doing anything wrong here or what is the issue

but when i run this query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * 
FROM reservation AS rs
INNER JOIN vehicles AS ve ON rs.vehicle_id = ve.vehicles_id
INNER JOIN customers AS cu ON rs.customerid = cu.customerid
LEFT JOIN checks AS ck ON rs.reservation_id = ck.reservation_id
LEFT JOIN credits AS cr ON rs.reservation_id = cr.reservation_id
```

i get this

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  rs  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    22   
1   SIMPLE  ve  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   crm.rs.Vehicle_id   1    
1   SIMPLE  ck  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    2    
1   SIMPLE  cr  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    5    
1   SIMPLE  cu  eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   crm.rs.CustomerID   1   Using where
```

the problem here is all they fields that i use in my joins are either an index or a primary key.
there are all primary

```
ve.vehicles_id
cu.customerid
ck.reservation_id
cr.reservation_id

and these are all indexes
rs.vehicle_id
rs.customerid
```

here is a checks of info

```
CREATE TABLE `checks` (
  `Checks_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customerID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `firstActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
  `lastActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
  `checkValue` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `dueDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Reservation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `isCashed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `cashingResult` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Checks_id`),
  KEY `customerID` (`customerID`),
  KEY `Reservation_id` (`Reservation_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


            CREATE TABLE `vehicles` (
              `Vehicles_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
              `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
              `size` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `maker` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `model` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
              `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
              `color` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              `oilChange` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
              `currentMillage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
              `oilChangeMillage` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
              `registrationExp` datetime NOT NULL,
              `insuranceExp` datetime NOT NULL,
              `dailyRate` double NOT NULL default '0',
              `weekleyRate` double NOT NULL default '0',
              `monthleyRate` double NOT NULL default '0',
              `addDate` datetime NOT NULL,
              `Active` int(1) NOT NULL default '1',
              `VINnum` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
              `licensePlate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
              `vehicleCost` double NOT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY  (`Vehicles_id`),
              UNIQUE KEY `VINnum` (`VINnum`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


        CREATE TABLE `credits` (
          `Credits_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
          `customerID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
          `creditValue` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
          `dueDate` datetime NOT NULL,
          `Reservation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
          `date` datetime NOT NULL,
          `firstActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
          `lastActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
          `paymentHistory` text NOT NULL,
          `paymentHistoryDate` text NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`Credits_id`),
          KEY `customerID` (`customerID`),
          KEY `Reservation_id` (`Reservation_id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    CREATE TABLE `reservation` (
      `Reservation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
      `Vehicle_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `CustomerID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `additionalDrivers` char(54) NOT NULL,
      `dateFrom` datetime NOT NULL,
      `dateTo` datetime NOT NULL,
      `pickupDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `dropoffDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `addDate` datetime NOT NULL,
      `reservationStatus` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1' COMMENT '0 canceled, 1 Reserved, 2 In Progress, 3 Completed',
      `totalDays` int(4) NOT NULL,
      `totalDiscount` char(6) NOT NULL,
      `totalFees` char(6) NOT NULL,
      `totalRent` double NOT NULL,
      `totalTax` double NOT NULL,
      `totalChecks` double NOT NULL,
      `totalOwe` double NOT NULL default '0',
      `totalPaidCash` double NOT NULL default '0',
      `totalPaidBankCard` double NOT NULL default '0',
      PRIMARY KEY  (`Reservation_id`),
      KEY `CustomerID` (`CustomerID`),
      KEY `Vehicle_id` (`Vehicle_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1033 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

so i am not sure why do i still get NULL for possible_key and key ?

what am i doing wrong?  all my primary key have the same value INT(11) unsiged.

thanks for your help guys

Comment: MySQL will try to query as efficiently as it thinks it can.  If it has to inspect more than approximately 1/3rd of all rows in a table, it will not use indices.

Comment: did you declare foreign key ..? and make index on these foreign key ?

Comment: not sure what is foreign key!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no WHERE conditions by which to filter, it makes sense that the first table listed will include all rows and therefore has no useful index to use.  In your case, scanning  all of the `reservation` table.

As for the `checks` and `credits` tables, you will have to show the table structure output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename \G`.  I can't see from the query you showed, why that would be the case.  I'm guessing that there might be column type mismatches between the indexed columns which prevent mysql from using them to compare rows.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `checks` (
 `Checks_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `customerID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `firstActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
 `lastActivity` datetime NOT NULL,
 `checkValue` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
 `dueDate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Reservation_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `isCashed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
 `cashingResult` int(2) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`Checks_id`),
 KEY `customerID` (`customerID`),
 KEY `Reservation_id` (`Reservation_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: please edit the original question with this info, and include all tables.

Comment: It appears that the reason it's doing a full table scan on `credits` and `checks` is that there are very few rows.  If there were more rows in those tables, the explain plan would probably show a join using an index.

Comment: I think it is not using index on checks and credits is because I am using a left join as you saild there are few rows. But the one that I still don't understand is vehicles! There are at least on row in vehicles that has no record in reservation.  So this should not give me null. Key length should be 21 and not 22 due to that record that does not exists in the database

Comment: There's nowhere in the explain plan that shows a key_length of 22; perhaps you're referring to the first line which shows rows 22?  Keep in mind that's just an estimate.

Comment: yes, Gavin 22 row it should return 21 rows. Not sure why would it say that.

Comment: Because it's not supposed to be an exact count.